# logical units to device units

Tags: windows, api, gdi

I've been struggling with a clipping problem with a window with **non-zero window origin** because I didn't realize SelectClipRgn required device units.

So given that I have determined the viewport origin and the window origin as follows...

```
POINT VP_Org, WN_Org;
GetViewportOrgEx (dc, VP_Org);
GerWindowOrgEx (dc, WM_Org);
```

and I have a clipping region R in logical coordinates, how does one convert R to device units for use in defining a clipping region?

In other words, how do I transform R so that the following works.

```
RECT R;
ClipRgn = CreateRectRgn (R.left, R.top, R.right, R.bottom)
SelectClipRgn (dc, ClipRgn)
```

I know that it looks something like

```
R.top = R.top - WN_Org.y +- VP_Org.y;
```

from experiment but don't know what sign to use for the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [LPtoDP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

> The LPtoDP function converts logical coordinates into device
>   coordinates. The conversion depends on the mapping mode of the device
>   context, the settings of the origins and extents for the window and
>   viewport, and the world transformation.

Comment: Ok, that's cool.  Would still like to know sign of viewport adjustment.

Comment: Can a RECT be treated as two POINTs?

Comment: @MikeD: Yes, the RECT layout is x1, y1, x2, y2. The same is done in `MapWindowPoints`. Not sure about the sign, maybe this helps: http://www.bobpowell.net/mappingmodes.htm